# Meaning of "nude" in Saxo Grammaticus

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

If you review the 1997 Evolution of the [Saxo Grammaticus, here](http://www.rostra.dk/latin/saxo.html), you will find they use the word "nude" many times, even for words that do not (I think?) mean "naked" or "bare".

I'm thinking it must mean something to do with word usage, e.g., "this word is used without an adjective" or something like that?

Here are a few examples:

> ictus, -us i.q.actio pulsandi, feriendi, vehemens motus 1 nude 2 c.gen.

> nuncupatio, -nis i.q. nomen a c.gen. b nude 2 i.q. nominatio, invocatio 3 i.q. actio pronuntiandi, promulgandi

> rogo, -avi I i.q.interrogo, quæro A additur quæstio indirecta 1 aliquem 2 aliquid 3 nude B sequitur super C nude 1 aliquem 2 aliquid 3 oratione directæ insertum II i.q. peto, flagito, hortor A aliquem 1 nude 2 sequitur (obi.) c. inf. 3 additur ut B sine acc.

How is "nude" being used here, and what is the meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I'm not an expert in grammatical terminology, from these examples, it looks like it means "alone"—that is, without another noun attached.

For instance, looking at your second example, and expanding the various abbreviations:

> nuncupatio, -nis
>
> 1. i[dem] q[uod] nomen
>    1a. c[um] gen[itivo]
>    1b. nude
> 2. i[dem] q[uod] nominatio, invocatio
> 3. i[dem] q[uod] actio pronuntiandi, promulgandi

Definition 1 says that *nuncupatio* is the same as *nomen* ("name"), and can be used either *cum genitivo* (with a genitive), or *nude* (alone). In other words, you can have the name **of** something, or just a name.

This notation is, I imagine, more useful when applied to verbs: even without these notes, I could guess that "name" would take a genitive, but I often forget which cases are used for each argument of a particular verb.

Comment: I think I understand now. Can you comment on the verb, and how "aliquem" and "aliquid" are being used alongside "nude" there?

Comment: @Josh "Someone" and "something"—that is, it can be used with either a person or a thing (or neither, _nude_).

Comment: This is somewhat, though not quite, similar to how we can use the word *bare* in English. A bare ablative is one without a praeposition, for examp.e

Comment: One would perhaps say *absol[utely]* in a modern dictionary.

Comment: It's perhaps worth stating the obvious and adding macrons: the word here is *nūdē*, the adverb of *nūdus* ([Lewis & Short II.B.2](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/nudus)) ("nakedly, simply").